# Compare table without join function

Tags: sql-server

I would like to match the first table, the second table. The first table must match the data in the second table, I gave the first pairing with. Therefore I can not use the function join.

I'm comparing the two tables, but the counting process takes more than 1 day due to the amount of data. How do I make this work in less time? I would appreciate your help.

Note: I can't join functions. Because I want to one to one matching. Please look at the picture.***[Click the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH3L2.jpg)***

```
DECLARE @Sayac1 AS INT = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #T1 );---50.000 data
DECLARE @Sayac2 AS INT = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #T2 );---100.000 data
DECLARE @Siralama1 AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @Siralama2 AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @T1column1 VARCHAR(16), @T1column2 NUMERIC(25, 2), @T1column3 DATE;
DECLARE @T2column1 VARCHAR(16), @T2column2 NUMERIC(25, 2), @T2column3 DATE;
DECLARE @T2column4 INT;
DECLARE @T1column4 INT;

Goto1:

WHILE @Siralama1 <= @Sayac1
    BEGIN
        Goto2:
        WHILE @Siralama2 <= @Sayac2
            BEGIN
                SELECT @T2column1 = Column1, @T2column2 = Column2, @T2column3 = Column3, @T2column4 = Column4 FROM #T2 WHERE Siralama2 = @Siralama2;
                WHILE @T2column4 IS NULL
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @T1column1 = Column1, @T1column2 = Column2, @T1column3 = Column3, @T1column4 = Column4 WHERE Siralama1 = @Siralama1;
                        WHILE @T1column1 = @T2column1 AND @T1column2 = @T2column2 AND @T1column3 >= @T1column3
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE #T2
                                SET Column4 = @T1column4 WHERE Siralama2 = @Siralama2;
                                SET @Siralama1 = @Siralama1 + 1;
                                SET @Siralama2 = 1;
                                GOTO Goto1;
                            END;
                        SET @Siralama2 = @Siralama2 + 1;
                        GOTO Goto2;
                    END;
                SET @Siralama2 = @Siralama2 + 1;
            END;
        SET @Siralama1 = @Siralama1 + 1;
        SET @Siralama2 = 1;
    END;
```

Comment: Please show SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements.  Better yet, enter them in sqlfiddle.com, paste the code here, and also provide link to sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Also: please remove anything not pertinent to answering the question.  (Remove irrelevant fields, rename fields to just "A" and "B", etc.)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  `join` is the natural way to compare tables in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do want a join, inside an update statement.

```
update #T2
    set column4 = #T1.Column4
from #T2 inner join #T1
     on #T1.Column1 = #T2.Column1 and #T1.Column2 = #T2.Column2 and #T1.Column3 = #T2.Column3
where #T2.Column4 IS NULL
```

I think this will do pretty much what you've tried with your query. It will change T2.column4 to be T1.column4 for the row where the first 3 columns match.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to compare whether data in two tables match. If not what is the mismatch.

Therefore your are writing a  loop and comparing it.

I suggest you use some function such as Binary checksum (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173784.aspx)
& go for a set based operation to 
find out the differences instead of the current loop which is taking time.

For Starters, here is a sample :

```
create table t3 (Code int,Val varchar(50),Val1 varchar(20))
create table t2 (Code int,Val varchar(50),Val1 varchar(20))


insert into t2 Values (1,'20', '25')
insert into t2 Values (2,'50',50)

insert into t3 Values (1,'20',25)
insert into t3 Values (23,'5',50)

Select * from ( Select BINARY_CHECKSUM(val,val1) chk, * from  t3 ) a
full outer join (Select BINARY_CHECKSUM(val,val1) chk, *  from  t2 ) b on a.chk = b.chk
```